# The argument type 'Future<dynamic> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<bool> Function()?'

Tags: flutter, dart

Soy nuevo en Flutter y no puedo solucionar este error, si alguien me pudiera ayudar a solucionarlo estaría agradecido.

Declaro esta función y el compilador me muestra que el error está en la declaración de la función.

```
Future _onWillPop() {
    //return _Pop(); //???
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) =>
        AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Are you sure?'),
          content: const Text('Do you want to disconnect device and go back?'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                child: new Text('No')),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  disconnectFromDevice();
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                },
                child: new Text('Yes')),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
```

Aquí es donde declaro la función y donde aparece el error.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onWillPop,                //Declaration highlighted as error
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Sensor'),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: !isReady
                ? Center(
              child: Text(
                "Waiting...",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.red),
              ),
            )

                : Container(
              child: StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
                stream: stream,
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<List<int>> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError)
                    return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');

                  if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                      ConnectionState.active) {
                    var currentValue = _dataParser(snapshot.data!);
                    return Center(
                        child: Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              child: Center(
                                child: new Object3D(
                                  size: const Size(300, 300),
                                  path: "assets/3d.obj",
                                  asset: true,
                                  angleX: currentValue.x,
                                  angleY: currentValue.y,
                                  angleZ: currentValue.z,
                                  zoom: 50,
                                ),
                              ),
                              color: Colors.blueGrey,
                            ),
                            Column(children: <Widget>[
                              Text('Current value from Sensor',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                              Text('${currentValue.x}',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 16)),
                              Text('${currentValue.y}',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 16)),
                              Text('${currentValue.z}',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 16))
                            ]),
                          ],
                        ));
                  } else {
                    return Text('Check the stream');
                  }
                },
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

- package:flutter_3d_obj

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety
lib/mpu6050_page.dart:129:18: Error: The argument type 'Future Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future Function()?'.

- 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
  onWillPop: _onWillPop,
  ^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\adria\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\adria\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Estás en stackoverflow Español, traduce tu pregunta para que puedas obtener respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Esto sucede porque la propiedad ***onWillPop*** necesita recibir una función de tipo Future que devuelva un bool, es decir, necesita un ***Future***

Recuerda siempre ponerle a tus funciones qué tipo de valor retornan, ya que si lo omites por default devolvera un ***dynamic***

Intenta declarando tu función _onWillPop de la siguiente manera

```
Future<bool> _onWillPop {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto arregla ese error, pero la funcion que retorna _onWillPop, showDialog es de tipo dynamic por lo que ocurre un error.